# random number in every testrun | JMeter Webdriver

Tags: selenium, random, webdriver, jmeter

I have a script, which create a new user in every testrun with a random number as name. So the users are unique.

But when I start a testrun in Ultimate Thread Group with more than one user it use always the same random-number.
Is it possible to create everytime a new one?

I tried to use propertys or reset a variable at the end, but it didn't worked.

Comment: Hi @Paili, can you provide the example code you are using to generate random names? Can you provide a minimum, complete, viable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: 1. Please post your code-examples. 2. Using random number is not a good way to guarantee "unique" names -> you should rather use something like a date-time-tag in the form of 20150828103524 which comprises the date 20150828 and the time 103524 -> which is unique if you are creating it within a timeframe greater than 1 second

Comment: Yes, i do so. I generate the username with a timestamp combine with a random number. I know it is not necessary, but more secure. Thank you anyway @drkthng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a unique date and time instead of a random number, it's much more reliable and helpful in some sense, than just a random number.

You could store something like this into a variable and use it for the name:

```
var uniqueDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("F").Replace(":", "-");
```

Comment: Just to add, when I use CI (Jenkins), I also pass a build number to my tests to make data even more unique (sometimes numbers must be short)

Answer (score 2):

JMeter provides [__UUID()](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) function which generates unique [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) structure each time it's being called.

```
var username = '${__UUID}'
```